# Changing shortcut to change views doesn't work. Is it possible? How?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, navigation

I tried to assign a new shortcut to changing views (Front, Left, Right) and it does not work.

I check conflicts and tried different keys combinations. How can I do that?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, pressing the "~" key brings up a pie menu that contains all the views, making them available for immediate selection. Not exactly what you were asking for, but maybe it will do in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

It's a conflict with Hide Collection. It has all numbers assigned. Because I tried combination with numbers alt+1 alt+2 ... to change views.
[image]